# Как правильно пишется (Не)зависящим

Tags: орфография, частица-не

Скажите: НЕ в данном случае пишется — вместе или раздельно: *по НЕзависящим от нас причинам*? И почему?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Правильно: **по независящим от нас причинам**

Розенталь  §70. Правописание не с причастиями [Как правильно пишется (Не)зависящим](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/430350/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%9D%D0%95)

Примечание 3. Если причастие употребляется **в значении прилагательного,** то и при наличии пояснительных слов не пишется слитно , например: **по независящим от редакции обстоятельствам (фразеологический оборот с именем прилагательным)** – рефлексы, не зависящие от воли человека (причастный оборот).

В Нацкорпусе встречаются обе формы написания примерно в равном количестве, но о правильности их нужно судить по приведенному правилу.

Answer (score 0):

В вашем пояснении следует исправить - выделить частицу "не". По тексту - при наличии пояснительных слов "не" пишется слитно. Иначе смысл затуманивает я, меняется на противоположный. Это  раз. Во-вторых. Я пишу слитно, если можно подобрать синоним без частицы "не". Например. Несмотря на все независящие от нас трудности. Несмотря на объективные трудности.

Comment: О каком "пояснении" вы говорите? Где, что и зачем надо исправить?